# Adding extra fields in the submit form of Awesome support plugin wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Can any1 guide me as how to add extra fields in the awesome support plugin wordpress other than the existing ones so as to store the newly added fields data with tickets that are submitted.
I checked the link http://support.themeavenue.net/plugins/wpas/add-custom-field-submission-form/ but it is somehow not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
/**
 * Add custom fields
 */
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'tut_add_custom_fields');

function tut_add_custom_fields() {
    global $wpas;
    if ($wpas) {
        $wpas->addCustomField( 'user_site_url', array( 'id' => 'user_site_url', 'label' => __(' User site URL','tut')));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/**
 * Register all custom fields after the plugin is safely loaded.
 */
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'wpas_user_custom_fields');

if ( function_exists( 'wpas_add_custom_field' ) ) {
    wpas_add_custom_field( 'my_custom_field',  
            array( 
                'title' => __( 'Your Site URL', 'awesome-support' ) ) 
            );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to code in PHP, you should create a dedicated plugin and follow samples [here](https://getawesomesupport.com/documentation/awesome-support/custom-fields/).

Comment: This answer is not enough and contains a link that may stop working in a later time, please edit your answer and place the code in the answer rather than a link